# for loop to unlist(), select vector element & convert class - loops, list, vector, selection

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm having problems in generalising a method of dealing with some 'problem data' - vectorised elements of a list. (I'm not entirely sure if I'm describing this accurately so please forgive my ignorance).

**Objective:**

I'm trying to compile a function that deals with the following problem automatically as the intention is to run / utilise this methodology repeatedly.

**Problem:**

I've pulled some sensor data from a db by a unit name (equipment the sensor is from), usually the sensor data comes as a vector (as per the desired outcome - below) but for certain units (where the data collectors are configured differently) it returns a list of vectors.

The number of elements within the vector relate to the number of units on site (i.e. if there are two units on site, /01 and /02, then the vector will contain 2 elements....and so on)

I want only the sensor data that pertains to that unit to be kept in the relevant column.

Not all units are configured in the same fashion, so I was only intending on running a a function when the class of the column has been confirmed that it is a list.

The number of sensors and their tags will be different each time (input into the main function).

**Intended methodology:**

1. Perform following checks and corrective measures over each column
2. Check the column class - check to see if class is a 'list'
3. If FALSE, do nothing.
4. If TRUE, perform following over each row with 'unlist_func'(sub function):
5. Check the end of the text string on each row of 'unit' column and extract unit_no
6. Unlist the current element and select the number in the vector that corresponds with the unit_no in the unit column
7. Ammend the column class to

**Reproducible problem:**

The following tibble is an example of what I'm working with:

```
unit <- c('a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03', 'a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03', 'a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03')
sen1 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), c(10,11,12), c(13,14,15), c(16,17,18), c(19,20,21), c(22,23,24), c(25,26,27))
sen2 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

sensor_data <- tibble(unit, sen1, sen2)
```

**Desired Outcome:**

```
unit <- c('a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03', 'a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03', 'a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03')
sen1 <- c(1,5,9,10,14,19,23,27)
sen2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

sensor_data_new <- tibble(unit, sen1, sen2)
```

**Attempt Thus far and Request:**

So as not to turn up empty handed I've posted up a hasty version of my intended methodology but my apologies, it's a work in progress and I appreciate there are errors within, but I was hoping to appeal to those out there to help if possible or suggest a different approach.

All advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
function(unit, sensors, date_from, date_to){
  
  #  ------  QUERYING TASK  ------------------------
  
  sensor_data       <- 'pulls sensor info from unit names'
  
  #  ------  SUB FUNCTION - Unlist function  -------
  
  unlist_func <-  function(df = sensor_data, j){
  
                  sensor_data_distinct <- df %>% 
                                          mutate(unit_no = str_extract(unit, '\\d$')) %>%
                                          select(unit_no) %>% 
                                          distinct()

                  for (i in 1:nrow(df))
                  {
                    if(length(df[, j[[i]] ]) => 1 & str_ends(df$unit, sensor_data_distinct$unit_no)){
                        unlist(df[i, j])
                        df[sensor_data_distinct$unit_no]
                    } else(sensor_data[, j])
                  }

  #  -------  STAGE 1 CLEANSING FUNCTION  -------------
  # unit will always be in column 1 and datetime always in column 2
  stg1_cleanse    <- for(j in 3:ncol(sensor_data)) {       # for-loop over columns
                        if (is.list(sensor_data[, j]) == TRUE){
                         lapply(unlist_func.....)
                        }
                      }
                  }
  
  #  -------  STAGE 1 CLEANSING FUNCTION  -------------
                        
  stg2_cleanse    <- 'further cleansing routine'
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can greatly simplify your function. This appears to produce the result you want. The custom function `extract_func` implements the rule in which each row is checked for length. If it is a single-element value, the single element is returned; if it is a vector, the element at the requested index is returned instead. We can then use dplyr's `rowwise` and `across` functions to apply this function to columns "sen1" and "sen2", passing "unit_num" as the index argument (when needed).

```
library(tidyverse)

unit <- c('a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03', 'a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03', 'a2b7/01', 'a2b7/02', 'a2b7/03')
sen1 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), c(10,11,12), c(13,14,15), c(16,17,18), c(19,20,21), c(22,23,24), c(25,26,27))
sen2 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

sensor_data <- tibble(unit, sen1, sen2)

extract_func <- function(data, idx) {

  # check for NULL data and convert to NA if it is present
  if (is.null(data)) {
      data <- NA
  }
  
  if (length(data) == 1) {
    return(data[1])
  } else {
    return(data[idx])
  }
  
}

sensor_data_clean <- sensor_data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    unit_num = as.numeric(str_extract(unit, '\\d$')),
    across(c(sen1, sen2), ~extract_func(., unit_num), .names = 'extract_{.col}')
  )

# A tibble: 9 × 6
# Rowwise: 
  unit    sen1      sen2      unit_num extract_sen1 extract_sen2
  <chr>   <list>    <list>       <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 a2b7/01 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        1            1            1
2 a2b7/02 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        2            5            2
3 a2b7/03 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        3            9            3
4 a2b7/01 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        1           10            4
5 a2b7/02 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        2           14            5
6 a2b7/03 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        3           18            6
7 a2b7/01 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        1           19            7
8 a2b7/02 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        2           23            8
9 a2b7/03 <dbl [3]> <dbl [1]>        3           27            9
```

Since you're just checking the length of the vector and then extracting a single element, you could do the following inline within `mutate` (though a predefined custom function like the above gives you a little more flexibility for the future).

```
sensor_data_clean <- sensor_data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    unit_num = as.numeric(str_extract(unit, '\\d$')),
    across(c(sen1, sen2), ~(.[min(length(.), unit_num)]), .names = 'extract_{.col}')
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it does seem that I was overly complicating the problem.  Just on the aspect of the across(), I want to be able to apply this across any cloumn of 'list' class.  Could I just utilise across(.cols = is.list(), ....... ? or utilise across(.cols = everything().... if it's looking for a length of greater than 1 anyway

Comment: `across(.cols = where(is.list), ... )` is probably what you want.

Comment: Ah, yes, perfect.  Thank you do much

Comment: Hi, Just to extend the question if I may :)  It seems to present issues if there are NULL value present in one of the vectored elements of the list, presenting this.  In order to deal with these NULL values, I'd intended on a liner interpolation function but I need first to address the issue of extracting the single values.  I can drop the NULL but ideally I'd prefer not to.  Your suggestions would again be greatly welcomed if you have any?

Comment: i.e....sen1 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), c(10,11,12), NULL, c(16,17,18), c(19,20,21), c(22,23,24), c(25,26,27))

Comment: You can check for NULL data in `extract_func`. I've modified my code above.

Comment: That's done it.  Thank you